# Tools to test the UI response for Android and IOS mobile applications

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, mobile-application

Requirement: To verify the UI response times for Android and IOS app.

I have an app for which I need to test the UI response times for the below scenarios.

1. Launch the app
2. Customer registration by providing personal information.

There are about 6-8 screens in the entire process and I would like to calculate the response time for each screen.

There is no load testing involved. Please suggest any tools. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out : https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/

Comment: @ShivamTripathi : Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention that I am a QA and have limited access to app. I just have the .apk (Android) and .ipa (IOS) files which I manually install on the devices. Can you please suggest something that a QA can check. Thanks.

Comment: https://testfairy.com/